# Angular11 + webcomponents/polyfills + IE11 == nojoy

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, web-component, custom-element, polyfills

We are developing a library of W3C Custom Elements (aka Web Components) using Angular 11 as a development tool, with [createCustomElement](https://angular.io/api/elements/createCustomElement). We need to support IE11, so we are trying to use [webcomponents/polyfills](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills). We need to support `<slot>`s so our components use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`. I have made a very simplified component in this manner (derived from [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-web-components-custom-elements-shadow-dom/)), and have a simple framework-less page to render this web component. When using the webcomponents-loader, the page in IE, the page errors with "IE11 SCRIPT28 Out of stack space" -- this error has some deep analysis by [morewry](https://github.com/morewry) in [this issue](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/972), however, there is no resolution. There were some fixes (linked in that thread) to `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, but those were 2.5 years ago; I am using the latest `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.5.0`, yet the Out of Stack Space error persists.  I have tried load the polyfills by different means, including `webcomponents-loader.js`, `webcomponents-bundle.js`, and the variations of `webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js`, but each has different issues.

Ultimately, the pressing issue is when loading `webcomponents-loader.js`, I get:

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js (65,290)
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 65
```

Very occasionally, I have gotten the error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'attachShadow'
```

... but I am not loading scripts asynchronously, and I clear my IE browser cache every time, so I don't understand why that variation would occur.  In an attempt to address that error, I loaded shadydom before webcomponentsjs (which should not be necessary), and I am back to the Out of Stack Space error.

From the Angular 11 build perspective, my `tsconfig.json` has `"compilerOptions.target": "es2015"` which gives me differential loading scripts.

`polyfills.ts` has

```
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
import 'document-register-element';
```

I have a small, complete demonstrative project [here](https://github.com/btmurrell/ng11-custom-el-shadow-ie11).  This web component renders error-free in Chrome, needless to say.

There are many posted questions on Stack Overflow and Angular and Webcomponents gh issues; Many are very old, and resolutions are not clear. I am on the latest version of everything (angular, webcomponents, and IE11) using a very simple example, and cannot get this to work. I am not clear if the solution is in Angular or Webcomponents, so I am posting here, and can go the appropriate github issues if we can zero in on this.

Thanks in advance!

---

Additional info:
by removing `document-register-element` from `polyfills.ts` and adding `//unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements` as the first script in my `index.html`, I get an error `ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'attachShadow'`, so then I add `//unpkg.com/@webcomponents/shadydom@1.8.0/shadydom.min.js` and then the error becomes `NotFoundError`. Other than many constants, the only information in that error seems to be `Symbol()_8.lacmbwvaqyq: undefined, Symbol(rxSubscriber)_i.lacmbwvaqyq: undefined,)`. The only place I can find a `Symbol` implementation seems to be from the `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.5.0` polyfill, apparently in their "platform" code. Any ideas on this situation?  Or recommendation on other tacts I should pursue?

One thing I cannot find distinguished is whether the implementation of `@ungap/custom-elements` is an alternative to `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` -- I suspect it is, however, ungap does not seem to have a shadyDOM implementation.

Even tho stackoverflow discourages gratitude comments, mine is high for any assistance on this matter!

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue with IE11, to fix it I removed `'document-register-element'` from the `polyfills.ts` and loaded it on page **before** my Angular bundles.

The issue is that `'document-register-element'` must be run **before** IE11 is shimmed with the ES6+ functionality (by `core-js`).

As `core-js` is now hidden by the CLI (it used to be in `polyfills.ts`) cannot adjust the order in which the browser parses the functionality and `'document-register-element'` works by shimming the browser based on what `es2015+` functions are available when it loads, if Angular has already shimmed the missing parts, `'document-register-element'` cannot determine what it needs to do correctly, so fails.

Also to note the author has now deprecated the library and has recommendations for replacements on [GitHub](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element).